# Saving state of Map to Flutter app with Provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView that is rendered based on the below structure. The Map has about 5 'String' key values, each with 1 List of 10-15 ItemModels. The isDone is flipped by calling the individual ItemModels with toggleDone(). This saves the bool state in the app, but it resets once the app is closed. I looked into sharedprefences, but -

1. I cant figure out how to encode this specific Map and then load the necessary values.
2. Is this even something I should be doing on the Model class,
   or the individual ItemModel classes?
3. Is there a way to encode only the bool values and then load those?

The ChangeNotifier class that holds the Map:

````
 ```
class Data extends ChangeNotifier {
   List<ItemModel> getData(name) => items[name];

        Map<String, List<ItemModel>> items = {
                'String': [
                  ItemModel(
                    title: 'Some text',
                    text:
                        'Some other text',
                    isDone: false,
                    duration: Duration(
                      hours: 0,
                      minutes: 0,
                      seconds: 10,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
            };
          }
````

The ItemModel:

```
class ItemModel {
  final String title;
  final String text;
  bool isDone;
  Duration duration;

  ItemModel(
      {this.text, this.title, this.isDone = false, this.duration});

  void toggleDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }
}
```

For each ItemModel in the List, an Item is rendered that looks like this. It takes the ItemModel value of isDone to set the isChecked property.

```
class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String text;
  final bool isChecked;
  final Function checkboxCallback;

  Item(
      {this.text,
      this.title,
      this.isChecked,
      this.checkboxCallback});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Checkbox(
              value: isChecked,
              onChanged: checkboxCallback,
            ),
            title: Text(
              title,
            ),
            subtitle: isChecked
                ? Text('')
                : Text(
                    text,
                  ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned the SharedPreferences only support persisting primitive values. What you can do, assuming you can guarantee unique key for each instance of `ItemModel` in the list, is to write your own wrapper around SharedPreferences:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

abstract class SharedPreferencesKeys {
  static const title = 'title';
  static const text = 'text';
  static const isDone = 'isDone';
  static const duration = 'duration';
}

class SharedPreferencesImpl {
  SharedPreferences _preferences;
  Future<SharedPreferences> get preferences async => _preferences ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  Future<void> write(String key, ItemModel value) async {
    final sharedPrefs = await preferences;
    await sharedPrefs.setString('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.title}', value.title);
    await sharedPrefs.setString('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.text}', value.text);
    await sharedPrefs.setBool('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.isDone}', value.isDone);
    await sharedPrefs.setInt('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.duration}', value.duration.microseconds);
  }

  Future<ItemModel> read(String key) async {
    final sharedPrefs = await preferences;
    final title = await sharedPrefs.getString('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.title}');
    final text = await sharedPrefs.getString('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.text}');
    final isDone = await sharedPrefs.getBool('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.isDone}');
    final microseconds = await sharedPrefs.getInt('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.duration}');
    return ItemModel(
      title: title,
      text: text,
      isDone: isDone,
      duration: Duration(microseconds: microseconds),
    );
  }

  Future<void> delete(String key) async {
    final sharedPrefs = await preferences;
    await sharedPrefs.remove('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.title}');
    await sharedPrefs.remove('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.text}');
    await sharedPrefs.remove('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.isDone}');
    await sharedPrefs.remove('$key_${SharedPreferencesKeys.duration}');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this! Do you know why am I getting the error " 'await' applied to 'int', which is not a 'Future'."? 
And do you have an opinion on where the best place be to instantiate the SharedPreferencesImpl class would be?

Comment: I'd need to see your code, apparently you're calling a wrong function that returns `int` instead of `Future<bool>` but I can't tell you which one without having a look. As for the place to instantiate that depends on you architecture. If you're just starting with Flutter, take a look at BLoC pattern. Also, take a look at `provider` and `riverpod` packages for dependency injection.